# Using Clang to get AST

Tags: clang, abstract-syntax-tree

I would like to use Clang to get to its AST to get some information about the variables and methods in a particular source file. However, I do not want to use the LibTooling facilities. I would like to, by hand, to write to code that would call the methods to parse the .cpp and then get the tree. I can not find any resources that tell me how to do this. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to learn how to drive Clang components to work with the compilation database, configure the compiler instance, and so on, then the Clang source code is a resource. Perhaps the source for the `ClangTool::buildASTs()` method would be a good place to start: see Tooling.cpp in the lib/Tooling/ directory of the source tree.

If your goal is to do an analysis that LibTooling doesn't support, and you just want to get the AST with minimal fuss, then either `ClangTool::buildASTs` or `clang::tooling::buildASTFromCode` might be of service. The ClangTool approach would be better if you need the compilation database to express compiler options, include paths, and so on. `buildASTFromCode` is fine if you have a standalone bit of code for lightweight tests. Here's an example of the ClangTool approach:

```
#include "clang/Tooling/CommonOptionsParser.h"
#include "clang/Tooling/Tooling.h"
#include "llvm/Support/CommandLine.h"
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

static llvm::cl::OptionCategory MyOpts("Ignored");

int main(int argc, const char ** argv)
{
  using namespace clang;
  using namespace clang::tooling;
  CommonOptionsParser opt_prs(argc, argv, MyOpts);
  ClangTool tool(opt_prs.getCompilations(), opt_prs.getSourcePathList());
  using ast_vec_t = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ASTUnit>>;
  ast_vec_t asts;
  tool.buildASTs(asts); 
  // now you the AST for each translation unit
  ...
```

Here's an example of `buildASTFromCode`:

```
#include "clang/Frontend/ASTUnit.h"
#include "clang/Tooling/Tooling.h" 

  ...
  std::string code = "struct A{public: int i;}; void f(A & a}{}";   
  std::unique_ptr<clang::ASTUnit> ast(clang::tooling::buildASTFromCode(code));
  // now you have the AST for the code snippet
  clang::ASTContext * pctx = &(ast->getASTContext());
  clang::TranslationUnitDecl * decl = pctx->getTranslationUnitDecl();
  ...
```

Comment: what I havent figured out yet, is how to run for example a MatchFinder on a single AST Unit. Each Tutorial i find will simply use the tool.run(frontendFactory) thingy
could you elaborate on how one is supposed to work with those single AST unit instances?

Comment: Is there a way with buildASTFromCode to generate ASTs for incomplete code? The AST is not getting generated in the cases where there are errors in the code. Are there any options for error-tolerant parsing?

Comment: @Julian (It's been > 4 years, but in case anyone lands here after gsearch ...) I think that the [LibASTImporter](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTImporter.html) allows traversal of pre-built ASTUnits.